# routing through a GVPE network

Tags: linux, routing, vpn

The following is a GVPE network (VPN) setup on Debian Linux systems. It is how I interpreted the two paragraphs starting at line 174 in the [GVPE README](https://github.com/enki/gvpe/blob/master/README). Sadly, there is not much detail and my knowledge of routing is inadequate.

I'm trying to setup my LAN to communicate with two remote GVPE nodes through a local GVPE node. The three GVPE nodes communicating fine between all of their .1 and .2 addresses. I can actually see ICMP traffic from 10.1.1.0/24 systems reach the remotes with tshark, but there are no replies. I guess a static route is needed on the remotes, but I haven't figured it out. For example, `ip route add 10.1.1.0/24 via 10.2.3.1 dev gvpe0` on atlanta didn't do it.

```
me@atlanta:~$ tshark -i gvpe0 -f icmp
Capturing on 'gvpe0'
  1   0.000000     10.1.1.4 -> 10.2.3.1     ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x72e3, seq=1/256, ttl=62
  2   1.008711     10.1.1.4 -> 10.2.3.1     ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x72e3, seq=2/512, ttl=62
  3   2.009655     10.1.1.4 -> 10.2.3.1     ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x72e3, seq=3/768, ttl=62
```

The setup details:

```
atlanta (remote, hosted VM)
  interfaces:
    gvpe0 10.2.3.1/16, eth0 10.2.3.2/24 (probably don't need eth0 here)
  routing:
    10.2.0.0/16 via 10.2.3.1 dev gvpe0 
    10.2.3.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.2.3.2 

buffalo  (remote, hosted VM)
  interfaces:
    gvpe0 10.2.2.1/16, eth0 10.2.2.2/24 (probably don't need eth0 here)
  routing:
    10.2.0.0/16 via 10.2.2.1 dev gvpe0
    10.2.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.2.2

brooklyn (local, net.ipv4.ip_forward=1)
  interfaces:
    gvpe0 10.2.5.1/16, eth0 10.2.5.2/24, eth0 10.1.1.13/24
  routing:
    10.1.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.1.13
    10.2.0.0/16 via 10.2.5.1 dev gvpe0
    10.2.5.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.5.2

router (local, static route to the GVPE GW)
  interface:
    switch0 10.1.1.1/24
  routing:
    10.1.1.0/24 dev switch0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.1
    10.2.0.0/16 via 10.1.1.13 dev switch0  proto zebra
```

Answer (score 0):

Each node you want to talk to through the tunnel will need to know a path to use to send packets back. How you do this depends on the network (perhaps there's a router you can configure, or perhaps each node needs it's own routing rule(s) adding).

e.g. ip route add  via